# Weird characters in perf output...

Tags: c++, linux, perf

I'm trying to debug a webkit build with Linux perf that I compiled with symbols.

The output of "perf report -g" has the symbols with half human readable and the other half alphanumeric values.

For example:

```
_ZN7WebCore12RenderObject18setAnimatableStyleEN3WTF10PassRefPtrINS_11RenderStyleEEE
    |
    |--91.30%-- _ZN7WebCore4Node14setRenderStyleEN3WTF10PassRefPtrINS_11RenderStyleEEE
    |          _ZN7WebCore7Element11recalcStyleENS_4Node11StyleChangeE
    |          _ZN7WebCore7Element11recalcStyleENS_4Node11StyleChangeE
    |          _ZN7WebCore7Element11recalcStyleENS_4Node11StyleChangeE
```

What's happening here?

What's _ZN7?

My hunch is that this is something to do with C++ and maybe I need to compile with more options to get the symbols to be represented in perf correctly.

ANY pointers here would be appreciated. I can't find anything about this anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: try piping the result to c++filt : perf report -g | c++filt

Answer (score 6):

These are so-called ["mangled names"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling):  The C++ compiler encodes type information into symbol names, so that the linker can correctly implement overloading, class scoping and namespaces without having to actually understand the C++ type system, and without having to support characters outside of basic alphanumerics and underscores.

You can turn these back into human-readable names with tools such as `c++filt` under Linux.

For example:

```
$ echo _ZN7WebCore12RenderObject18setAnimatableStyleEN3WTF10PassRefPtrINS_11RenderStyleEEE | c++filt 
WebCore::RenderObject::setAnimatableStyle(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::RenderStyle>)
```

Or in your case, `perf report -g | c++filt` will probably do what you want.